# stack overflow when searching in std::map

Tags: c++, stack-overflow, stdmap

This code causes stack overflow exception when running for some reason:

```
neuralnetwork::CPerceptron::inputEvent(const neuralnetwork::IConnection * origin, double value)
    std::map<std::reference_wrapper<const IConnection>, float64_t, _CPerceptronComparator>::iterator it = m_inputValues.find( std::ref( *origin ) );
    if ( it == m_inputValues.end() )
    {
        throw "Some error";
    }
    ...
}
```

_CPerceptronComparator looks like this (it is needed because std::ref has no operator<):

```
class _CPerceptronComparator
{
public:
_CPerceptronComparator()
{
}

bool operator()( const std::reference_wrapper<const neuralnetwork::IConnection *> & val1,
                 const std::reference_wrapper<const neuralnetwork::IConnection *> & val2 ) const
{
    return (val1.get()) < (val2.get());
}

bool operator()( const std::reference_wrapper<const neuralnetwork::IConnection> & val1,
                 const std::reference_wrapper<const neuralnetwork::IConnection> & val2 ) const
{
    return &( val1.get() ) < &( val2.get() );
}

bool operator()( const std::reference_wrapper<neuralnetwork::IConnection> & val1,
                 const std::reference_wrapper<neuralnetwork::IConnection> & val2 ) const
{
    return &( val1.get() ) < &( val2.get() );
}
};
```

I added some more code so maybe you can help. This is how I add an input connection:

```
 void CPerceptron::addInputConnection( IConnection * inConn )
 {
    m_outConnections.insert( std::ref(*inConn) );

    m_inputValues.insert( std::pair<std::reference_wrapper<IConnection>, float64_t>( std::ref( *inConn ), 0.0f ) );
    m_isInputReady.insert( std::pair<std::reference_wrapper<IConnection>, bool>( std::ref( *inConn ), false ) );
 }
```

Note: I know std::make_pair is easier to use, but I replaced it in the hope it causes my problems. You know, its impossible to see through that type it returns with. This solution might be harder to read but is fool proof.

The error: Unhandled exception at 0x002C2EC9 in Neural Network.exe: 0xC00000FD: Stack overflow (parameters: 0x00000001, 0x00102FFC).

Call stack:

```
Neural Network.exe!std::_Iterator_base12::_Orphan_me() Line 192 C++
Neural Network.exe!std::_Iterator_base12::_Adopt(const std::_Container_base12 * _Parent) Line 165   C++
Neural Network.exe!std::_Iterator_base12::operator=(const std::_Iterator_base12 & _Right) Line 129  C++
Neural Network.exe!std::_Iterator_base12::_Iterator_base12(const std::_Iterator_base12 & _Right) Line 121   C++
Neural Network.exe!std::_Iterator012<std::bidirectional_iterator_tag,std::pair<std::reference_wrapper<neuralnetwork::IConnection const > const ,double>,int,std::pair<std::reference_wrapper<neuralnetwork::IConnection const > const ,double> const *,std::pair<std::reference_wrapper<neuralnetwork::IConnection const > const ,double> const &,std::_Iterator_base12>::_Iterator012<std::bidirectional_iterator_tag,std::pair<std::reference_wrapper<neuralnetwork::IConnection const > const ,double>,int,std::pair<std::reference_wrapper<neuralnetwork::IConnection const > const ,double> const *,std::pair<std::reference_wrapper<neuralnetwork::IConnection const > const ,double> const &,std::_Iterator_base12>(const std::_Iterator012<std::bidirectional_iterator_tag,std::pair<std::reference_wrapper<neuralnetwork::IConnection const > const ,double>,int,std::pair<std::reference_wrapper<neuralnetwork::IConnection const > const ,double> const *,std::pair<std::reference_wrapper<neuralnetwork::IConnection const > const ,double> const &,std::_Iterator_base12> & __that)    C++
Neural Network.exe!std::_Tree_unchecked_const_iterator<std::_Tree_val<std::_Tree_simple_types<std::pair<std::reference_wrapper<neuralnetwork::IConnection const > const ,double> > >,std::_Iterator_base12>::_Tree_unchecked_const_iterator<std::_Tree_val<std::_Tree_simple_types<std::pair<std::reference_wrapper<neuralnetwork::IConnection const > const ,double> > >,std::_Iterator_base12>(const std::_Tree_unchecked_const_iterator<std::_Tree_val<std::_Tree_simple_types<std::pair<std::reference_wrapper<neuralnetwork::IConnection const > const ,double> > >,std::_Iterator_base12> & __that)   C++
Neural Network.exe!std::_Tree_const_iterator<std::_Tree_val<std::_Tree_simple_types<std::pair<std::reference_wrapper<neuralnetwork::IConnection const > const ,double> > > >::_Tree_const_iterator<std::_Tree_val<std::_Tree_simple_types<std::pair<std::reference_wrapper<neuralnetwork::IConnection const > const ,double> > > >(const std::_Tree_const_iterator<std::_Tree_val<std::_Tree_simple_types<std::pair<std::reference_wrapper<neuralnetwork::IConnection const > const ,double> > > > & __that)    C++
Neural Network.exe!std::_Tree_iterator<std::_Tree_val<std::_Tree_simple_types<std::pair<std::reference_wrapper<neuralnetwork::IConnection const > const ,double> > > >::_Tree_iterator<std::_Tree_val<std::_Tree_simple_types<std::pair<std::reference_wrapper<neuralnetwork::IConnection const > const ,double> > > >(const std::_Tree_iterator<std::_Tree_val<std::_Tree_simple_types<std::pair<std::reference_wrapper<neuralnetwork::IConnection const > const ,double> > > > & __that)  C++
Neural Network.exe!std::_Tree<std::_Tmap_traits<std::reference_wrapper<neuralnetwork::IConnection const >,double,neuralnetwork::_CPerceptronComparator,std::allocator<std::pair<std::reference_wrapper<neuralnetwork::IConnection const > const ,double> >,0> >::find(const std::reference_wrapper<neuralnetwork::IConnection const > & _Keyval) Line 1553  C++
Neural Network.exe!neuralnetwork::CPerceptron::inputEvent(const neuralnetwork::IConnection * origin, double value) Line 94  C++
```

Let me note, that if I debug the map, it contains one element as it should. (Or at least it's size tells me it has 1 element.)

It doesn't matter what type of iteration I use to iterate through the map, it will give an error on the first query. I use Visual Studio 2013.

I'm really helpless right now.

Sorry for the bad formatting.

Comment: What is the stack trace at that point?

Comment: You may be interested to know that `_CPerceptronComparator` is not a legal identifier for you to use in C++.  Names beginning with underscore and an uppercase letter are reserved.

Comment: The code you've posted looks OK and shouldn't be giving you a stack overflow. It is likely that your problem is elsewhere, perhaps a buffer overrun or writing to an invalid reference somewhere is corrupting the stack.

Comment: Added some more information. I'm just noting it for the new readers, so they don't turn away instantly.

Comment: Are you declaring large arrays on the stack, perhaps? That might trigger the overflow.

Comment: @JohnZwinck The funny thing that I deliberately used this name for that reason. No one else will use such name! On second thought it was a rather stupid line of argument.

Comment: @templatetypedef Not at all. Everything is stored in heap as in this example above. Right now I'm just trying to connect 3 neurons, nothing big is going on anywhere else. It must be a bad pointer somehow as noted about by Jason C. Can't figure it out, nothing seems to be broken.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was caused by infinite loop (the only reason for stack overflow I've ever seen in fact).

```
void CPerceptron::addInputConnection( IConnection * inConn )
{
    m_outConnections.insert( std::ref(*inConn) );

    m_inputValues.insert( std::pair<std::reference_wrapper<IConnection>, float64_t>( std::ref( *inConn ), 0.0f ) );
    m_isInputReady.insert( std::pair<std::reference_wrapper<IConnection>, bool>( std::ref( *inConn ), false ) );
}
```

I was inserting to the m_outConnections in a function called addInputConnection, which created a circle in the graph (in the neural network), so propagating the result caused an infinite loop (the propagation function is not in the post).

It's a good example of how easy to miss such small thing, but otherwise useless post. Delete it IMO.

Answer (score 0):

I've taken your code and created a mockup I can compile and run.  If failed to compile under gcc 4.8.1 unable to make template substitutions.  On a hunch that this is related to the use of reference wrappers (and that you are using a different compiler and standard library) I defined an operator< for class IConnection and removed the wrappers and _CPerceptronComparator.  It compiled, and seems to run.

You can see the [code in coliru here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ff221d19bd6dac31).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <stdexcept>

typedef double float64_t;

namespace neuralnetwork {

    class IConnection {
        float64_t _value = 0.0;
    public:
        IConnection( float64_t v ) : _value(v) {}
        float64_t get() const { return _value; }
        friend inline bool operator< ( const IConnection & lhs, const IConnection & rhs ) { return lhs.get() < rhs.get(); }
    };

    class CPerceptron {
        std::map<const IConnection, float64_t>
        m_inputValues, m_isInputReady;
        public:
        void inputEvent(const neuralnetwork::IConnection * origin, double value);
        void addInputConnection( IConnection * inConn );
    };

    void CPerceptron::addInputConnection( IConnection * inConn )
    {
        m_inputValues.insert( std::pair<IConnection, float64_t>( *inConn, 0.0f ) );
    }

} // namespace neuralnetwork

void neuralnetwork::CPerceptron::inputEvent(const neuralnetwork::IConnection * origin, double value)
{
    std::map< const neuralnetwork::IConnection, float64_t >::iterator
        it = m_inputValues.find( *origin );
    if ( it == m_inputValues.end() )
    {
        throw std::runtime_error("Some error");
    }
//   ...
}

int main( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
    neuralnetwork::IConnection ic( 1.0 );
    neuralnetwork::CPerceptron cp;
    cp.addInputConnection( & ic );
    cp.inputEvent( & ic, 2.0 );
    std::cout << "No stack overflow here!" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

This is the output I get

```
g++-4.8 -std=c++11 -O2 -Wall -pedantic -pthread main.cpp && ./a.out
No stack overflow here!
```

**Update**:

Per the observation from the OP I've created two versions that use address of object to order in map:

Object created on the stack (fails):

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/02d1f262a75b1d25

Object created on the heap (fails):

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/728cf77040143f21

The STL implements ordered map as a binary tree, which uses the copy constructor to copy your object into the map(binary tree). It uses the comparator you provide (or the operator<) to figure out where to insert it (and later to figure out how to find it), but since you are using the address of your object to order it and that changes when it gets copied - problem!

Using std::shared_ptr works (with one added level of indirection).  They say any problem in computer science can be solved with one level of indirection - seems to work here.

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6aa631675133289b

**Update 2:**

Simpler yet, get rid of `get()` function and use the pointer to the object as the key in the map, compare pointers directly for less than in `operator<`:

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f1376a39c8b287df

Comment: Sadly, even if it works, it is not good. You order by value, I wanted to order by address in the heap. Value can change - and it will in every cycle of the learning, this will be a neural network after all - and changing the behaviour of the operator< of an object after placing it in a map **will** cause serious problems.

Comment: @user2741959 Ahh, I missed that sorry.  That might be a clue as to what is wrong, actually, let me think about it.

Comment: Let me note your solution with defining an operator< is much more simple so I use it istead now.

Comment: @user2741959 The STL implements ordered `map` as a binary tree, which uses the copy constructor to copy your object into the map(binary tree).  It uses the comparator you provide (or the operator<) to figure out where to insert it (and later to figure out how to find it), but since you are using the address of your object to order it and that changes when it gets copied - problem!  I'll update my answer.

Comment: Update 1 is invalid, update 2 is correct, but I implemented operator< as you described, so that was not a problem at all. I updated only a small thing: I use std::less now since using "<" or ">" for pointers is indefinite in c++, as I later found on the internet. Please don't bother anyway, the code already works perfectly.

Comment: I'm glad it was somewhat helpful.